# Hyperlink won't work when creating a unique url? C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="itemsforsale" runat="server"
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ElmtreeConnection  %>"
     SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM Products WHERE Products.CategoryId = @CategoryId">

     <SelectParameters>
         <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="CategoryId" 
              QueryStringField="CategoryId" Type="Int32" />
     </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:HyperLink ID="hyperlink" runat="server" 
     NavigateUrl='<%# "ItemsForSale.aspx?CategoryId"+Eval("CategoryId") %>' 
     Text="Beauty"></asp:HyperLink>
```

This is my markup. I'm not getting any errors when loading the page, however the link is not working. Can anyone give me any insight as to why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An equal sign is missing in the URL:

```
NavigateUrl='<%# "ItemsForSale.aspx?CategoryId=" + Eval("CategoryId") %>'
```

If the HyperLink is not in a databound control, you must call its `DataBind` method (or the `DataBind` method of the Page itself) in `Page_Load` to make sure that its databinding expression is evaluated:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        hyperlink.DataBind();
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however this still hasn't solved the problem.

Comment: I added another suggestion in my answer.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! Been at this for days, you're a life saver.

Answer (score 1):

You're essentially creating a Url to the address ItemsForSale.aspx. Prefix your URL with ~/ to have it recognized as a route relative to your base url.

Comment: I tried that, and it's still not working. When I click the hyperlink, it's dead. It's not directing me to any page.

Comment: Have you confirmed that you can navigate to that page at all?

Comment: Yes, can definitely navigate to the page.